# Regex: How to replace a ColumnName with tablename.ColumnName using BRE regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a condition string:

```
condition = "PlanSliceGUID='[PlanSliceGUIDMV]' and PlanSliceGUID > 'uhj'"
```

Where `PlanSliceGUID` is `columnName` and `'[PlanSliceGUIDMV]'` is a variable. I just need to replace `ColumnName` i.e. `PlanSliceGUID` with `tableName.PlanSliceGUID` excluding the `'[PlanSliceGUIDMV]'`.

String should look like this after replacement:

```
tableName.PlanSliceGUID='[PlanSliceGUIDMV]' and tableName.PlanSliceGUID > 'uhj'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\bPlanSliceGUID\b
```

and replace it with:

```
tableName.$0
```

Full example:

```
String condition = "PlanSliceGUID='[PlanSliceGUIDMV]' and PlanSliceGUID > 'uhj'";
        System.out.println("Result: "+ condition.replaceAll("\\bPlanSliceGUID\\b","tableName.$0"));
```

Live demo:http://ideone.com/cP6OLA

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp:

```
condition = condition.replaceAll("([^\\[]|^)(PlanSliceGUID)", "$1tableName.$2");
```

It allows you to replace `PlanSliceGUID` by `tableName.PlanSliceGUID` when `PlanSliceGUID` is not preceded by `[`. So, it also works if the variable is named `[PlanSliceGUID]`.

If you want it to be case-insensitive, and replace with the same case, you have to use the [`i` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

```
condition = condition.replaceAll("([^\\[]|^)(?i:(PlanSliceGUID))", "$1tableName.$2");
```

If you want it to be case-insensitive, but to replace with a fixed case, you have to specify what you want to replace with instead of `$2`:

```
condition = condition.replaceAll("([^\\[]|^)(?i:(PlanSliceGUID))", "$1tableName.PlanSliceGUID");
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Florent and Amit. It works as expected!! :) . But there is one more bottle-neck. How to make this replacement case-insensitive? eg : It should work even if I provide the columnName all in small letters in my condition string.

Comment: @user3425148 Updated my answer to add a part on case-insensitivity.